# Changing CPU architecture in build.prop won't effect browser

Tags: browser

Web pages using `NavigatorObject` can query my platform and see that it is armv7l. for testing reasons i need impersonate i686 CPU. when i edit `ro.product.cpu.abi` at system/build.prop it doesn't change anything. are there more files to edit?

Comment: Why don't you just use the emulator that comes with the SDK? It's available as an x86 device so it would just fit. You also can't change your CPU's ABI in some file and be done. Just like on desktop PCs, an app can query the hardware for capabilities including the ABI.

Comment: @GiantTree no app. i just want change my browser info. now javascript can query my ABI. how can i change that? it is possible

Comment: Possibly Firefox (or a fork of it) can change all the information with an extension. I am pretty sure there is something that can make your device appear as a different one (by changing the UserAgent or similar).

Comment: @GiantTree for testing reasons i have to use the stock browser. how about that mate?

Comment: AFAIK the stock browser does *not* give you the option to change anything (e.g. UserAgent string). So you need to either use an actual i686 device or an x86 emulator.

Comment: Im not at home to post a complete answer, so its a comment until then. Here is how you do it. Using stock browser, go to address bar and type "about:debug" (w/o ""). Then enter browser settings, tap newly added choice DEBUG. Adjust as needed the UAString.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN it have only a few profiles. if i try PC it makes me look like a PC to destination website and damage my test. there is a server-side program that renders the page based on UA it gets

Comment: @user137070 you stated in your question you "need to impersonate i686 CPU", that's what its doing.